# cut a hole with boolean modifer not working

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I'm attempting to cut a hole in a plane. I added a cylinder object, added the Boolean modifier to the plane, selected "cylinder" and "Difference", but no hole is made. The lower half of the cylinder just highlights, moving/deleting the cylinder reveals a hole-less plane.

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can i cut a hole in the plane?

Comment: Modifiers are dynamic, that is their reason for being. As soon as you move the cylinder away from the plane, there is no interaction between plane and cylinder, hence nothing to subtract. You need to _Apply_ the modifier if you want the operation to be set in stone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the plane is [*non-manifold*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/599). It's a 2D object, which has no volume.

Either make it manifold by giving it volume (e.g. with a *solidify modifier*), or use the knife project tool instead of a boolean modifier:

1. Add a circle

   [image]
2. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on the plane so that both the circle and the plane are selected, and the plane is active (yellow outline).
3. Enter edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>), and align the view so that the circle outlines the hole you want to cut. In your case top view (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>) is probably good.
4. Press *Knife project* in *3D view > tool shelf > Tools > Add*:

   [image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Used 'knife project' as suggested, but I don't get a Clean cut. http://i.imgur.com/0ThqMPs.png

edit: seems to have been caused my subdivision surface.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is completely wrong. Cutting holes in planes using the Boolean mod works perfectly. Has been for a long time.

Comment: @ArnaudMeuret  The boolean modifier has only worked as the OP expected [since the *bmesh* solver was introduced in 2.78](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/Modelling/). The knife project tool does what the OP wanted, both when the question was asked and now.

Answer (score 1):

Undoubtedly the *Knife Project* would be the better alternative, when you would apply the *Subdivision  Modifier* it could work:

[image]