# How to cut holes in a plane with multiple meshes without adding to the plane?

Tags: mesh, objects

I'm trying to use the boolean difference tool to cut holes in a plane with a mesh. Whenever I try I end up with a weird 3d object completely different from the plane that I'm looking for. Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

[image: The shape I'm trying to cut out of the plane]

[image: The result of the boolean difference modifier]

Comment: it is unclear what you doing

Comment: I select the plane in the first picture, move it up so it intersects the 3d shape, apply the boolean - difference modifier to the plane with the 3d shape as the object.

I would expect the result of this to be a plane with sections cut out to match the 3d shape, what I actually get is the second picture.

Comment: This is because the boolean modifier needs to know where the inside and outsides of objects are. Since a plane doesn't have a defined inside or outside, it gets confused. [Try using knife project instead](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16002/599).