# Cube with cutout corner

Tags: mesh

Can you cut the cube with cutout corner

example:

[image]

Comment: see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object

Comment: Use [Intersect tool](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Modeling) via *Mesh* > *Faces* > *Intersect*.

Comment: search on google for BoolTool Addon ... pretty easy to use to create the mesh you are looking for. It's interactive too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [*Boolean Modifier*](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html)

1. Add a new cube with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and doublicate the cube with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
2. position the second cube where you want to cut out the main cube

   [image]
3. Select the cube you want to cut out
4. Go to the *Modifier* tab in the *Properties* window and choose the *Boolean Modifier*

   [image]
5. Set the *Operation* to *Difference*
6. Choose the 2nd cube in the Object list box
7. Click *Apply* (*Object Mode*)

   [image]
8. Delete the 2nd cube.

Note: After applying the *Boolean Modifier* the mesh could be not suitable for a good topology.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

This can be done by using the **[Boolean modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans)**. Simply create two cubes ,we will call them **A** and **B**, **A** being the object you want to cut and **B** being the region you want to cut. To better match the question we shall subdivide Cube **A**.

Then add the Boolean modifier to Cube **A**. This can be found in the modifiers tab.

Next, in the Boolean modifier settings, set **Operation** to *Difference* and **Object** to the object which defines the region you wish to cut out .In our case this is Cube **B**.

Then all you have to do is hit *Apply* delete Cube B and you are done!