# Boolean Difference Doesn't Work

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm trying to subtract a mesh with another mesh, in this case a cube from a cube. But every time i use a boolean modifier (difference) it just creates the shape instead.
[image: Like this.]

Comment: attach your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for detail investigation

Comment: What do you mean "creates the shape"?

Comment: It sounds like you're getting an additive boolean instead of a subtractive one. [Read this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object/34460#34460) to understand why.