# Boolean Difference Issue

Tags: modifiers

So I am stumped here in creating a 3D model of my house and cutting the holes for the doors and windows in the exterior walls for the most part is working great. However 1 wall is giving me fits in that the hole is cut when looking from the outside (I turned door object off in the image to show the hole better); however looking from the inside that wall simply looks "pushed" in and is solid (not cutting inside face of wall)? Now the strange thing is that if I slide the entire door in the wall to the right of left the hole of course moves with the door and it cuts both faces as expected.
See images attached:
[image: Outside Wall]

[image]

[image]

Couldn't add video so here is a screen capture of after I slide the door down the exact same wall and the hole is completely through both faces! I move it back where it belongs and interior face is filled into the cutting object but exterior face of the cutting object remains wireframe only as in original image #1???

Any thoughts?
TIA!
Cheers!
Rick...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object/34460#34460

Comment: Thanks but this isn't helping the issue. As stated in my initial post I have all the settings correct with the "cutting" object. I am not sure why this particular "hole" only removes the exterior face as other windows and door (7 others) cut through both faces. If I start to slide this "hole" object either way in the way the hole magically completely cut through both faces? I'll try and edit my post with a video of this actually happening.

Comment: Problems with Boolean generally are caused by non-manifold geometry. There appear to exist problems with wall geometry and / or cutter object. For such simple object like wall it could be simpler to add 2 loopcuts in that place and fill in hole you don't need even with Ngons (if you don't subsurf the mesh). Or enter Edit mode for the wall and remove doubles, recalc normals, search for non-manifold and correct places with problems etc